# Material 3 Active indicator color

Tags: android-layout

The primary swatch of my app is Green, but the Material 3 Bottom Navigation bar has the active indicator of color light purple. I want to change it to light green. Can someone tell which property in XML should be changed?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Mnv6.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change the color of active indicator bottombavigationview material You? material3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70397792/how-to-change-the-color-of-active-indicator-bottombavigationview-material-you-m)

Answer (score 5):

the property that works for me to change the color of the indicator is the following.

```
 <item name="colorSecondaryContainer">@color/your_color</item>
```

This you have to add in the style of your application as seen below.

[Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPcB0.jpg)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Please add the code of your picture to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add new style on themes:

```
<style name="BottomNavigationView">
    <item name="colorSecondaryContainer">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Add theme information on BottomNavigationView

```
android:theme="@style/BottomNavigationView"
```