# How to set itemActiveIndicatorStyle on BottomNavigationView in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am trying to convert my Android application to Jetpack Compose

I have a `BottomNavigationView` configured with property `app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle` set according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70397792/how-to-change-the-color-of-active-indicator-bottombavigationview-material-you-m).

This allows for the "pill shaped" background material 3 style selection indicator on the Bottom tab nav view.  But I cannot find how to do this with Jetpack Compose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**`colors`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/NavigationBarItemDefaults#colors(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color)) attribute in the [`NavigationBarItem`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#(androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowScope).NavigationBarItem(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.material3.NavigationBarItemColors,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource)) defining the **`indicatorColor`**

```
NavigationBar {
    items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
        NavigationBarItem(
            icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = item) },
            label = { Text(item) },
            selected = selectedItem == index,
            onClick = { selectedItem = index },
            colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors(
                indicatorColor= Green
            )
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I was using BottomNavigation instead of Material's NavigationBar.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put it in themes:

```
    <item name="colorSecondaryContainer">#D5EBFF</item>
```